# change cell background color in winform datagrid C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid

I want change background datagird cell base on value in c# windows application. for instance if cell value is 3 cell background color set to blue if cell value equal 2 cell background color change to red .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use CellFormatting event:

```
private void dataGridView_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 1)
        {
            if ((int)e.Value == 3)
                e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Blue;
            if ((int)e.Value == 2)
                e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want some thing like this

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    if (row.Cells[someColumnIndex].Value == 3)
        row.Cells[someColumnIndex].Style.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
    else if (row.Cells[someColumnIndex].Value == 2)
        row.Cells[someColumnIndex].Style.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
}
```

I hope this helps.